# Any detail documentation for Transporter app? How can I download Transporter app?

Tags: xcode, macos, application-loader

As the Application loader removed by apple. Transporter is the new way to upload apps.

Any detail documentation for Transporter app? How can I download Transporter app?

Answer (score 0):

[Transporter](https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/en.lproj/static.html) is command-line tool integrates with a developer’s content management system in order to help deliver app metadata in bulk using XML.

You can use Transporter to deliver your pre-generated content, in a Store Package, to the iTunes Store, Apple Books, and App Store.

Comment: I believe Transporter is an app? Apple mention in WWDC 2019 session

Answer (score 0):

It's available on the Mac App Store: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12.